# exec() php always returning array (size=0) empty?

Tags: java, php, exec

I'm trying to execute jar file in my php program.
I'm testing with this simple example :

```
exec('java -jar "C:\wamp\www\Hello.jar" myName', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

but it always printing

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

BTW the jar file does `System.out.println("hello "+args[0]);` and I'm testing it in cmd and it is working fine.

Please help I'm struggling with this problem since two days.

Comment: Try using absolute path when you call the java executable

Comment: It doesn't work :( 
i tried this echo exec('whoami'); and it is printing 'autorite nt\système'

Comment: You might want to check if you have disabled safe mode in your php.ini configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
exec('java -jar \"C:\wamp\www\Hello.jar" myName', $output);
```

instead of

```
exec('java -jar "C:\wamp\www\Hello.jar" myName', $output);
```

Comment: i tried this echo exec('whoami'); and it is printing 'autorite nt\système'

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
exec("/path_to_java -jar C:\wamp\www\Hello.jar myName", $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to escape backslashes: replace `\` with `\\`
2. You should build CMD and JAR strings separately. (Good programming)
3. Redirect errors to output with `2>&1` to display errors in output.

Simple:

```
$JAR = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\Hello.jar';
$CMD = sprintf(
    'java -Xmx32m -jar %s myName 2>&1'
    ,escapeshellarg($JAR)
);
exec($CMD, $Output, $Status);
var_dump($CMD, $Output, $Status);
```